# Disable Bluetooth "roaming" on Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth

So, my Macbook Pro (15-inch, 2018) are often bluetooth "roaming" and connecting to devices (like my headphones) despite being on battery power with closed lid. I would very much like to disable this *feature* – seems like a bit of a security/privacy concern as well.

Any ideas on how to disable bluetooth when lid is closed?

Comment: When you say roaming are you referring to the setting to allow bluetooth devices to wake your Mac? That would keep the circuit powered and not sleeping when the system enters sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your MBP do not disconnect bluetooth when closing the lid. So if you turn on devices known (like your headphones) they will connect together. I also found this annoying when I wanted to connect my headphones to my phone but they always connected to my MBP...

You could install [blueutil](http://braumeister.org/formula/blueutil) and [SleepWatcher](https://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and set a .sleep code to do `"/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p 0"` when going to sleep mode.

To use SleepWatcher, make a shell script in your home directory named .sleep and give it permission with the chmod command.

You also can do a .wake code to turn bluetooth back on with `blueutil -p 1`

You can find out how to use sleepwatcher [here](https://www.kodiakskorner.com/log/258)